# How use Hibernate Criteria with searching in Postgresql JSON and use with Lateral

Tags: java, json, postgresql, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

On the client side we have endpoint for searching with filter.

On backend I have method for searching in Postgresql DB. One of the option - search into jsonb field.

Before this day I searched over **values** and **keys**. And my code was:

```
if (appFilter.getSearchValue() != null) {
    criteria.add(Restrictions.sqlRestriction("UPPER(values::text) LIKE '%" + appFilter.getSearchValue().toUpperCase() + "%'"));
}
```

SQL analog (`UPPER` - is not mandatory):

```
SELECT *
FROM application
WHERE UPPER(values :: TEXT) LIKE '%some text%'
```

Now I need search **only into values**. SQL query for this purpouse:

```
SELECT *
FROM application, LATERAL json_each_text(application.values :: JSON)
WHERE value :: TEXT LIKE '%some text%';
```

How I can add this into restrictions? Maybe there ara any another variants for searching into values?
Hibernate 5.0.12

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Restrictions.sqlRestriction will be insert in generated sql after WHERE clause with AND so you need add something like this

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.sqlRestriction("this_.id IN (SELECT application.id FROM application , LATERAL json_each_text(values :: JSON) WHERE UPPER(value :: TEXT) LIKE '%" + appFilter.getSearchValue().toUpperCase() +"%')"));
```